# moving an svg element on a page within a container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a project that lets you place a text element onto an SVG.  Once that element is placed, I then want it to be draggable so that it can be repositioned.  currently, I can place the text element, and I can do edit it, however, when I go to move it, that is where I am having problems. Currently, the issue is that when I click and move a text element, it moves.  But when I release and click again, the element will move on its own always to the same spot. When I go to click it, then it will move off the page entirely.

I have looked and attempted several different ideas including these sources:

https://dev.to/tvanantwerp/dragging-svgs-with-react-38h6

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/

I believe, it has to do with the fact that a mouseclick reads according to the whole page, but I need it to be a specific area.

This is my canvas element that has the SVG:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SvgCanvas = (props) => {
  const [Dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ x: 20, y: 20 });

  const DragClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.attributes);
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(true);
    setOrigin({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  };
  const DragMove = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (Dragging) {
      // var x = parseFloat(e.target.getAttributeNS(null,"x"))
      // console.log(x)
      // e.target.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x+.1);
      console.log("Origin= X: "+origin.x+", Y: "+origin.y);
    console.log("Current= X: "+e.clientX+", Y: "+e.clientY);
     setCoordinates({ x: e.clientX - origin.x, y: e.clientY = origin.y });
    }
  };
  const DragRelease = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(false);
  };
  var lnk = props.details.url;
  const TextBoxArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < props.details.box_count; i++) {
    //console.log("for");
    //console.log(props.Meme[i]);
    const y = '20';
    const x = '30';
    TextBoxArray.push(
      <text
        key={i}
        id={"MemeBox" + i}
        //y={`${coordinates.y}`}
        // x={`${coordinates.x}`}
        transform={`translate(${coordinates.x}, ${coordinates.y})`}
        fontSize={props.Meme[i] ? props.Meme[i].range : "16"}
        fill={props.Meme[i] ? props.Meme[i].color : "black"}
        onMouseDown={(e) => DragClick(e)}
        onMouseMove={(e) => DragMove(e)}
        onMouseUp={(e) => DragRelease(e)}
      >
        {props.Meme[i]
          ? (document.getElementById("MemeBox" + i).textContent =
              props.Meme[i].text)
          : null}
      </text>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div id="SvgCanvas">
      <svg>
        <image key={props.details.id} x="10" y="10" href={lnk} />
        {TextBoxArray}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SvgCanvas;
```

And, the app.js file

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import SvgControls from "./components/svgcontrols";
import SvgCanvas from "./components/svgcanvas";
import MemeChooser from "./components/selector";
import "./style/meme.css";

function App() {


  const [Meme, setMeme] = useState([]);
  const [MemeText, setMemeText] = useState([]);
  const MemeSet = (e) => {
    setMeme(e);
  };
  const TextSet = (MemeEditArray, InitialArraySetFlag) => {
    if (!InitialArraySetFlag) {
      setMemeText(MemeEditArray);
    }
    if (InitialArraySetFlag) {
      var MemeEditArrayCopy = [...MemeText];
      MemeEditArrayCopy[MemeEditArray["id"]] = MemeEditArray;
      setMemeText(MemeEditArrayCopy);
    }

  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Meme Maker</header>
      <div id="MemeMaker">
        <SvgCanvas Meme={MemeText} details={Meme} />
        <SvgControls getter={MemeText} setter={TextSet} details={Meme} Create={document.getElementsByName(SvgCanvas)} />
        <MemeChooser click={MemeSet} />
        {
        //console.log(ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).querySelector(SvgCanvas))
        }


      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I appreciate any suggestions, that you may have to help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while, I was able to come up with a solution for my issue.  What I did was add a starting variable, and then making adjustments off of that.

```
const DragMove = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (Dragging) {
      // var x = parseFloat(e.target.getAttributeNS(null,"x"))
      // console.log(x)
      // e.target.setAttributeNS(null,"x",x+.1);
      console.log("Origin= X: "+origin.x+", Y: "+origin.y);
    console.log("Current= X: "+e.clientX+", Y: "+e.clientY);
     setCoordinates({ x: e.clientX - origin.x, y: e.clientY = origin.y });
    }
  };
```

The problem was that when I was chaning the coordinates based on the click position, I was not adjusting for the initial position of the text.

```
const [Dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ x: 20, y: 20 });

  const DragClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.attributes);
    e.preventDefault();
    setDragging(true);
    setOrigin({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  };
  const DragMove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var startX = coordinates.x;
    var startY = coordinates.y;
    if (Dragging) {
      setCoordinates({
        x: startX + e.clientX - origin.x,
        y: startY + e.clientY - origin.y,
      });
    }
  };
```